# Tag nodes in rundeck based on their connection status

Tags: rundeck

I want to run a job(or any other method) on a set of nodes in Rundeck to test the successful connection with the nodes and then tag them as node_name_failled and node_name_succeed. Is this possible to do so using plugins or without them so that it can be achieved in one click

Currently, I'm able to do so by externally parsing the node's execution status and modifying the resource model. But this needs to navigate away from the UI

Answer (score 0):

In Rundeck [Enterprise](https://www.rundeck.com/enterprise) you can use [health check](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/healthchecks.html) feature and later dispatch your jobs with some [filter](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/healthchecks.html#job-filter) based on their status. A good way to do that in Community Edition is to call the jobs via [API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html) or [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/commands/) wrapped in some bash script that detects the status node before.

[Here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest#36bbd9c4-3186-56f4-aae2-90f5c9f097a8) you have an example to call a job using API and [here](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/commands/#run) using RD CLI.

EDIT: Also you can build your own health check system based on [this](https://healthchecks.io/), take a look at [this](https://blog.lazkani.io/posts/monitoring/building-up-simple-monitoring-on-healthchecks/) and [this](https://blog.lazkani.io/posts/monitoring/simple-cron-monitoring-with-healthchecks/).